# How to Implement Contains logic in Oracle SQL for Multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle

**Scenario**

Each Online User has a set of skills assigned to him, Based on their skills they need to be mapped to a specific team, For which I need to check all the skills and if a certain set of skills are present assign him a team.

[image]

**My Implementation till now**

I used a CASE statement to check skills and if they match exactly give the name to that entry.

[image]

**Problem I am facing**

If the user is assigned more skills to help other teams then these conditions fails and it goes to ELSE condition.

So I was thinking if it is possible to include contains logic that will check if certain skills are present for the user then assign him a team according to that, And it is also possible a User is part of two teams, So if two skill set matches then two teams should be assigned to him, In CASE statement it is 
not possible to achieve this.

I have gone through REGEXP, but  I guess that also will not help.

Let me know if more clarity is needed.

Comment: I'd consider a separate table for these mappings between SKILLS and TEAMS.

Comment: We don't have your tables, and don't know your desired output. At least provide a minimum reproducible test case with sample data.

Comment: you're trying to solve a datamodel restriction with a sql query. Add the mapping table to your data model and rewrite your query.

Comment: Sure will update the question